# Creating Separate Dataframe for each Series inside a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have list of series:

[image]

I need to store every single series (which is inside a list) to a corresponding dataframe output. Tried using a for loop with enumerate() but cannot seem to make it work.

**Expected value would be:**
*Series0* -> *Dataframe0*
...
*Series4* -> *Dataframe4*

Comment: `df_list = [pd.DataFrame(s) for s in series_list]` ?

Comment: Hello @Arne. Thanks for replying. However, what I expect to accomplish is to store every single series to a corresponding dataframe output.

Comment: Could you give an example? I'm not sure what you mean by "store to a corresponding output".

Comment: Hello @Arne. Tried your suggestion and I found out a way to make it work on the problem that I have by simply accessing each series inside the dataframe. Not the solution I was hoping for but still helped me accomplish the requirement for my problem. Appreciate your help and sorry for the late response!